# jQuery show input inside column onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <th>Column 1</th>
      <th>Column 2</th>
      <th>Column 3</th>
   </tr>

   <tr>
      <td class='core'>
          <div>Result OK</div>
          <input type='text' name='editResult' style='display:none'>
      </td>
      .
      .        
      .
   </tr>

</table>
```

With jQuery I want to handle a click event on td class. When I click, the div must hide and the text input must appear.

I can't use ids or classes for child elements (div and input).

Any helps?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
$(".core").click(function(){
    $(this).find("div").css('display', 'none');
    $(this).find("input").css('display', 'block')
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wq928est/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using tag/element selector of jquery, you can read more about it from : https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

So the code will be like

```
$(".core").click(function(){
    $(this).find("div").hide().end().find("input").show();//using chaining
});
```

or

```
$(".core").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this); //cache data
    $this.find("div").hide();
    $this.find("input").show();
});
```